# UWP: How to coerce the value of a DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm working on my first Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App right now and just learned that the dependency property system implementation of the Windows Runtime seems to be less powerful than that of WPF. Having a lot of experience in WPF, I miss the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` type, or more precisely, the `CoerceValueCallback` that you can specify on it.

How does value coercion work for dependency properties in UWP Apps? The only solution that I see is to do it by resetting the value using `SetValue()` in the property changed callback method, but wouldn't that break data binding? I need value coercion for dependency properties on a custom templated control (derived from `Control`), so how am I supposed to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

CoerceValueCallBack is not supported by UWP Apps. I tried some like this before and the only one solution that I found was resetting the value as you did.